# How can I install themes for Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, themes

I am rather new to Mac, but I am trying to get familiar with Terminal and I want to change its theme. I am a bit confused on how to go about installing Solarized themes I am seeing so much of around the net. I am able to get the theme installed for vim, but I want it for just my general terminal usage.

I see some suggesting to install SIMBL but then I read if you have Lion, SIMBL is not needed with the color support that it has.

And then I've seen a suggestion to just "double click" to install, I am not entirely sure what is meant to be double clicked, the `Solarized Dark ansi.terminal` file?

My concern is running something that I am not sure what it is going to do. So anyone who could shed some light on this process, that would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Use ITerm2 (which is free btw), not Terminal -- ITerm2 offers many more options, and lets you split windows.

Answer (score 14):

Just open up terminal, go to the preferences and select the theme (the .terminal file)

[image]

Comment: Running 10.8, Import... displays the .terminal file in light gray "unselectable" font.

Answer (score 4):

Double-Clicking a .terminal file will not "run" anything, it will just install the configuration in Terminal. At the end you will get to the same result by double-clicking and by importing the settings from Terminal directly.

Comment: You can configure a .terminal file to run a command after opening it, i.e. when you specify a command to run once opening a new tab or window in a theme's configuration the .terminal file inherits this. So it can and may run commands.

Answer (score 2):

Using the 'save link as' option on the Github site for these themes didn't work, as noted in another answer. I dug in and noticed that the XML file formats were different when comparing the export of built-in themes and the ones I was trying to import.

When I did the **Download .zip** (the link is on the RHS of the main github window) and expanded the .zip file, it resulted in getting `Solarized Dark.terminal` and `Solarized Light.terminal` files which were import-able.