# How can I import a .terminal file using the command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, script

I'm writing a (Bash) script to automate setting up my Mac environment and would like to do [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27878/how-can-i-install-themes-for-terminal), except using the command line only. I'd also like to make that theme the default.

I have a .terminal file exported and all ready to go, I just can't figure out how to do this programmatically. Is there a documentation for this somewhere that I'm missing?

... or would these be easier using AppleScript? Never done that before though.

Comment: Why do you want to make this setting from a shell and not directly from within `Terminal`?

Comment: @danielAzuelos So I can automate the process.

Comment: How do you intend to run this shell script?
From a `Terminal`?

Comment: Well, from a shell at least. If I had to do it from a Terminal, hopefully this automation script is the only one I'd have to run in the default Terminal settings.

Comment: → Matt: do you have to do this configuration more than once (i.e. on more than one account or on more than one computer)?

Comment: @danielAzuelos Hopefully not -- my idea is to be able to re-configure my own workstation whenever I re-install the OS or something. For years I was using Windows and I hated having to reconfigure everything manually, and with Mac being a Unix system it's nice that I can more easily script things.

Comment: @Matt - did you ever manage to do this? I'm also looking for a way to import as default, for the same reason :)

Comment: No, but I'll be pursuing this again later this year, probably the apple script or automator route.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `open` command, followed by the preference change:

```
open ~/MyTerminalSettings.terminal
defaults write com.apple.terminal "Default Window Settings" -string "MyTerminalSettings"
defaults write com.apple.Terminal "Startup Window Settings" -string "MyTerminalSettings"
```

The `open` command will further open a new Terminal window, but the script will continue running in the original window, and you can close the new window when convenient.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but the basic bricks you will have to use to write
your shell script.

1. Check that `Terminal` isn't running to avoid corrupting its plist:

   ```
   if ps ax | grep '[/]Terminal' >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
       echo Terminal running! >&2 && exit 2
   fi
   # go ahead
   ```

   beware to the `[/]` which is here to avoid to `grep` your `grep`
   command which will be always successfull.
2. Convert your `Terminal` plist to a text file with:

   ```
       
   plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
   ```
3. Strip your `.terminal` file from its header, let's says its name is
   `imported.terminal`

   ```
   sed -n '/<dict>/,/<\/dict>/p' imported.terminal >tmp.terminal
   ```
4. Insert this `tmp.terminal` plist within the
   `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`
    inside the right dictionary.

   This will need some context analysis to do it right.
   I'd chose `perl` if I had to do it, but `awk`, `ex`, or `sed` might
   be easier with a few lines and testing.

Comment: Might be kind of tricky to not have Terminal running while you have a script running in Terminal :-)

Comment: I thought Matt wanted to do this from a shell and not directly from a Terminal because he is not doing this from a Terminal (for example through a `ssh`). But this should be clarified.

Comment: Either way. Whichever is easier.

Comment: As Patrix noted it, one path will be hard. One can't easily modify `Terminal` plist if the shell doing the task is forked from this same `Terminal` program. When `Terminal` will terminate, it will overwrite all the modification done thus far. This was the reason for my suggested step 1.

Comment: True, okay, understood.

Comment: I think you should be able to perform step 4 without scripting it yourself. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57960/how-can-i-export-text-substitutions-from-lion-for-import-into-mountain-lion